# Animate light without the mesh

Tags: mesh, transparency, emission

I've got an animation consisting of an animated noise texture plugged to a color ramp plugged to an emission shader.

What I want now is that the underlying mesh is not rendered, I just want to see the small emission parts to be seen.

Looking at my example GIF I want the white parts of the mesh to be invisible and the blue parts are my emission which can be seen. How would I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this setup:

[image: Original material: noise texture, color ramp, emission shader]

Create this setup which is a mix between an *Emission* and a *Transparent* node with your *Noise Texture* as factor (in Eevee don't forget to choose *Material → Settings → Blend Mode → Alpha Blend*):

[image: Updated material: mixes emission with transparent]

Comment: Will that also work with Cycles? Cannot check that right now.

Comment: yes of course with Cycles as well

Comment: Thanks for your help!